# FirstViewController is not working when Second ViewController is removed from its superview

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, subview

I'm using a UIStoryBoard to allow the FirstViewController to add the view of second ViewController as a subview. On removing the sub view using the following method

FirstViewController.m

```
  - (IBAction) btnMoveTo:(id)sender
{

 UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
 UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Second"];
 vc.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
 self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
 [self presentModalViewController:vc animated:NO];

}
```

SecondViewController.m

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
   self.view.opaque = YES;
   self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}

 - (IBAction) withDraw:(id)sender{
     [self.view removeWithZoomOutAnimation:2 option:nil];
    }
```

When I access the withDraw Function, the view of the SecondViewController is removed and firstViewController is back. However when I use the button to access the - (IBAction) btnMoveTo:(id)sender function. It doesn't work. Nothing really happens. Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing views with view controllers. View controllers are objects that control views, so for the first line you wrote,

> I'm using a UIStoryBoard to allow the FirstViewController to add the view of second ViewController as a subview. On removing the sub view using the following method

you cant add a view controller as a subview of another view controller. You present a view controller that manages its own views, and you can add UIViews as subviews of a UIViewController. A `UIViewController` manages `UIView`s.

The problem you are having with the code you posted, is that when you trigger the withDraw: function, you are removing the **view** of the view controller. Not the view controller itself. You need to dismiss the SecondViewController to gain access of the FirstViewController again.

Comment: Actually, @Siddharthan did not write about adding a view controller as a subview, but adding "the view of second ViewController as a subview".